# Data Protection Manager System Protection Backups Failing

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, backup, data-protection

I'm just starting to setup DPM 2010 in a test environment with a Domain Controller and a File Server. Everything seem to be working fairly well and I can get all of my backup jobs to succeed except for the "Computer\System Protection" backups.

Both servers are running fully up to date 64 bit Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise with Service Pack 1. The error that is being provided is:

> DPM cannot create a backup because Windows Server Backup (WSB) on the protected computer encountered an error (WSB Event ID: 517, WSB Error Code: 0x8078001D). (ID 30229 Details: Internal error code: 0x809909FB)

[This Microsoft Knowledge Base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2182466/en-US) describes the issue perfectly and provides a hotfix. I downloaded the hotfix, moved it onto the affected server, attempt to run it and receive the following error:

> The update is not applicable to your computer.

I've verified that I have indeed downloaded the 64 bit version. According to [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winservergen/thread/a597edf5-054d-43fd-ada4-311312ae02cb) the hotfix got rolled into Service Pack 1, yet I'm still experiencing the issue. Both machines do have the Windows Server Backup feature installed.

Can anybody point me in the right direction? What am I missing?

Comment: What is the size of the volume where you are placing the system state component, like Sysvol and AD, is one of them of more of 2TB?

Answer (score -1):

How much free space do you happen to have?  A system state backup requires a bit of space in order to succeed.

Also, what service pack are you running?  It looks like you should be ok after SP1 on Windows 2008 and 2008 R2.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/chrad/archive/2010/05/11/dpm-2010-before-you-get-started-get-your-pre-reqs-out-of-the-way.aspx